# Will there be security vulnerable if you left your wallet address and password in public?

Tags: security

So usually we got no password or `x` as password but my wallet got an password but since usually there isn't a password for wallet I'm wondering if I left my `wallet address` and its `password` in public will there be security vulnerable? Or others can't access your wallet without the secret phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password is used to decrypt your wallet's `.keys` file.
No one can access your wallet without having this file and the password used to decrypt it.

Alternatively, your wallet could be stolen by someone being in possession of your *Restore seed*.

---

Having only your password and your Monero address, nobody can steal your wallet or see the funds "in" it.